# How to always pre-populate nested form attributes with the Reform gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reform

I have a `Financing` model with `has_many: :professional_investments`.

To edit the `Financing`, the main form has a nested form for the `professional_investments`.

I decided to display a fixed list of 8 `professional_investments` for now, as the `Cocoon` gem does not play well with Trailblazer's `Reform`.

I use two `Reform` form objects: a `FinancingForm`, and a nested `ProfessionalInvestmentForm`:

```
class FinancingForm < Reform::Form
  collection :professional_investments,
    form: ProfessionalInvestmentForm,
    prepopulator: :prepopulate_professional_investments,
    populate_if_empty: :populate_professional_investments!,
    skip_if: :professional_investment_blank?

  def prepopulate_professional_investments(options)
    [8 - professional_investments.size, 0].max.times do
      professional_investments << ProfessionalInvestment.new
    end
  end

  def populate_professional_investments!(fragment:, **)
    ProfessionalInvestment.new unless professional_investment_blank?(fragment: fragment)
  end

  def professional_investment_blank?(fragment:, **)
    fragment['professional_investor_id'].blank? && fragment['amount'].to_d.zero?
  end
end
```

In the controller, I create the form object, and pre-populate it:

```
class FinancingsController < ApplicationController
  def edit
    @financing_form = FinancingForm.new(@financing)
    @financing_form.prepopulate!
  end

  def update
    @financing_form = FinancingForm.new(@financing)
    @financing_form.prepopulate!
    if @financing_form.validate(financing_params)
      @financing_form.save
    end
  end
end
```

It works, except that blank `ProfessionalInvestment` are saved as well in the collection, as if the `skip_if:` parameter had no effect.

If I don't call `@financing_form.prepopulate!` in `update`, the blank records are not saved, as intended. But then, if there are validation errors, only the existing records are displayed, not the full pre-populated 8 items list.

How to prevent these blank records from being saved, while still displaying the whole pre-populated nested list in the `update` action?